# Need to create sql trigger that will send out html email to a customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to set something up through sql server 2005, that will automatically send a welcome message to new customers. Through prophet 21, every time a new customer is entered into the system, they are given a unique 9-digit number by the system. These are stored in a table called "customer". My database email is already set up and I have a profile.

I'm thinking something like this should work?

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE (customer id is not already present in table))
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'whoever@customeremail.com', 
          @profile_name = 'P21 Alert',
          @subject = 'Welcome!',
          @body_format = 'HTML'
          @body = 'Thank you for ordering product <product ID>, welcome to our company';
    END
END
GO`
```

Please help or point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger needs to account for the fact that more than 1 row can be inserted at a time (think `INSERT INTO... SELECT .. FROM`).

Since you'd want to send an email to each customer individually, you're pretty much looking at a cursor to loop through one row at a time, and **you absolutely, positively don't want a cursor in your trigger body** as it is very likely to cause performance problems.

So, you want your trigger to insert rows to a holding/queue table, and then write a SQL job to read rows from that table in a cursor loop and send emails out.

Comment: thank you! could you point me somewhere that has directions on how to create a job for this circumstance?

Comment: You can read about [cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180169%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [sp_add_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182079%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).